# How to convert subtitles from IDX/SUB to SRT?

Tags: software-rec, media, subtitles

My WD HD Media Player supports only SRTs. How to convert subtitles from IDX/SUB to SRT?

Answer (score 1):

here's a link at AfterDawn.com
[link text](http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/convert_subtitles_from_sub-idx_to_srt.cfm)

although as NiklasS says, you'll probably have more success getting an SRT file from one of the subtitle sites. Converting can cause all sorts of issues with syncing the sound correctly, so it will save you more time getting the correct SRT file forthe film you've gotten hold of.